# How to change firebase email without reauthentication

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I implemented a button in my app that allows the user to change their email using Firebase.

```
 @IBAction func resetEmail(_ sender: Any) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Change Email", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertController.addTextField { (textField : UITextField!) -> Void in
            textField.placeholder = "Enter New Email Address"

              let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: .default, handler: { (action : UIAlertAction!) -> Void in

            //Reset Email

                let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser
            if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil{
                currentUser?.updateEmail(to: textField.text!) { error in
                    if let error = error {
                        print(error)
                    } else {
                        print("CHANGED")
                        let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
                        let name = user?.displayName!
                        let ref = Database.database().reference().child("main").child("users_sen").child(name!).child("email")
                        ref.setValue(textField.text!)

                    }
                }
            }

            })


        alertController.addAction(saveAction)
        }
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: {
            alertController.view.superview?.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            alertController.view.superview?.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.alertClose(gesture:))))

        })
    }
```

However, when I run it and I try to change the email it gives me this error:

```
UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=This operation is sensitive and requires 
recent authentication. Log in again before retrying this request.
```

and tells me to re-sign in order to change the email. How do I avoid this? How do I change the email without re-signing in?

This is how I change the password:

```
  // Password updated.
             let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser
            currentUser?.updatePassword(to: textField.text!) { error in
                if let error = error {

                } else {
                    // Password updated.
                    print("success")

                }
            }

            let userEmail = Auth.auth().currentUser?.email
            self.currentPassword = textField.text!

            let credential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(withEmail: userEmail!, password: textField.text!)

            currentUser?.reauthenticate(with: credential) { error in
                if let error = error {
                    // An error happened.
                } else {
                    // User re-authenticated.
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

Base on Firebase's [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#re-authenticate_a_user), you need to re-authenticate the user when performing this type of action.

> Re-authenticate a user Some security-sensitive actions—such as
>   deleting an account, setting a primary email address, and changing a
>   password—require that the user has recently signed in. If you perform
>   one of these actions, and the user signed in too long ago, the action
>   fails with an error. When this happens, re-authenticate the user by
>   getting new sign-in credentials from the user and passing the
>   credentials to  reauthenticateWithCredential.

```
let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
let credential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(withEmail: "email", password: "password")

user?.reauthenticate(with: credential)
{ error in
   if let error = error {
      // An error happened.
   } else {
      // User re-authenticated.
      user?.updateEmail(to: "newemail")
      { error in

      }
   }
}
```

Comment: almost every line is giving me an error is the swift 4?

Comment: i only want to change the email. is it possible to do that only without updating the password

Comment: the code I posted above will not change the password , just the email. but re authentication is necessary when changing attribute like email hence the need to enter the password again or just pass if if you already have it in your app

Comment: I used the same reauthentication to change the user's password. but I entered the current email because firebase has that option but I am having a hard time changing the email because firebase does not give firebase current password. I updated my question to show how I update the password.

Answer (score 1):

To change user email without re-authentication you can also leverage Cloud Functions. An example course of action could be:

1. Create a function that accepts user access token and new email address as parameters
2. In the function, verify access token and get the user ID from it
3. In the function, call 
   `admin.auth().updateUser(userId, { email: newEmail })`
4. Call the new function from the client

*Note: This solution is less secure because the user intent is not verified by additional authentication. Therefore anyone getting hold of the user's device could change their email address.*

Comment: This is not correct. As per the documentation: Refresh tokens expire when a major account change is detected for the user. This includes events like password or email address updates. It doesn't matter what you use to do it, Google Cloud functions, your own backend, or something else.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions

Answer (score 0):

If you use email and password to authenticate a user you should to do something like this.

1. You have to re-authenticate user using credential
2. Re-authenticate user
3. Update email

Before don't forget to get current user in your class and import Firebase like this :

```
...
import Firebase
class Blabla {
...
var currentUser: User? {
   return Auth.auth().currentUser
 }
```

Then :

```
func updateUserEmail(newEmail: String, password: String) {

// 1. Get the credential
guard let currentEmail = currentUser?.email else {return}
 var credential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(withEmail: currentEmail, password: password)
```

You can't get directly `password`, so you must ask to the user his password by a textfield or other.

```
// 2. Re-authenticate the user 
//(To change mail or password, the user must to be authentificate a short time ago !!!)

    self.currentUser?.reauthenticate(with: credential, completion: { (result, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("ERROR: ", error?.localizedDescription)
                return
            }

             //3. Update email
             self.currentUser?.updateEmail(to: newEmail, completion: { (error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print("ERROR: ", error?.localizedDescription)

                }else {
                    //Do something, for example present an alert of confirmation..
                }
            })
        })
```

All of the code in the same function from the step 1.